# Create a Filter for Closest Value to a Specific Decimal Range

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, equation

I've created a spreadsheet for choosing resistor combinations for an RC Operational Amplifier.  I've used a list of available capacitors and resistors for my limiting values to produce values of one of the resistors based on the resistance and capacitance values of the available (standard) components.  The values in my tables look like 7.23436793078690.  I wish to apply a filter that will find the values closest to a whole number (1592.00188622182000).  Then I wish to apply another filter that will compare those values to a list of available resistors and highlight resistors closest to the desired value.  Many of the returned values of R2 are negative values so I also wish to filter values of R2<0.

For this spreadsheet I've used the equation R2=(Req)(R1)/(R1-Req), which is an equation to determine Req, for parallel resistors, that is solved for R2.  In Column 1, the Rows are populated with values for available (standard) resistors.  All other columns are populated with the equation for R2.  The value for Req is obtained from another table in the Workbook that uses available (standard) capacitor values.  Therefore, Columns B and beyond are labeled R2(C=.47 uF), for example.  Essentially, Columns B and beyond reference the available (standard) capacitor values.

I wish to highlight the values I discussed in the first paragraph so I can quickly scan the workbook for the best possible value of R2.  Then I can quickly determine the values of R1 and C to complete my task and minimize the tolerance for the given op-amp application.

I have some C++ programming knowledge and I have enough experience with Excel so I should be able to understand where and how to do what I wish to do but I wish to get some advice and direction from a more experienced Excel user.

*****UPDATE*****

Since my first post, I've done some research.  It seems like the easiest approach would be to apply a "closest to" filter.  I've attached a screenshot of a small portion of my workbook, which contains the equation for the "closest to" filter, a partial range of available resistor values, and the results for my filter.  I have multiple tabs in my workbook.

I lied.  I'm unable to post an image until I gain 10 reputation.  I have 6 reputation.  If you're reading this post and you're able to contribute to my reputation, please contribute.

This is my equation: =INDEX(A3:BZ26,MATCH(MIN(ABS(A3:BZ26-CB3)),ABS(A3:BZ26-CB3),0))

The equation format is: =INDEX(rng,MATCH(MIN(ABS(rng-value)),ABS(rng-value),0))

My formula seems to be correct but it returns "#VALUE!".

Comment: You can use evaluate formula to see what the different parts are returning.  But did you enter your formula as an array formula?  by holding down **ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  No, I did not hold "ctrl+shift" while hitting "enter".  However, I did so after reading your post and now I get #N/A instead of #VALUE!.  I'm not sure if that's progress.  I originally attempted to step-through the equation but I have little experience with that process. A current step-through seems to work for every step but "INDEX('1'!A3:BZ26,#N/A)".  This step was the only step that provided "#N/A" for the evaluation.  I wish I could post a screenshot but I don't have the reputation yet.  :(

Comment: That actually IS progress. It usually means your MATCH function is not finding an exact match.  Pull the MATCH function out of your total formula, and test it separately to see what it returns.